# Pass Dbcontext to inner method being disposed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dispose, dbcontext

First off - apologies if this is trivial.  I've done some searching but can't find anything specifically relevant. Almost all of the questions I've found have concerned nested using statements - which does not apply in my case.

**The problem:**
I have a method which instantiates an instance of my DbContext. This instance is then passed into a private method which performs some actions, the context is then disposed of in the outer method. As soon as I try and use the context in the inner method, I get the good old exception:

> The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed

**The Question:**
What have I missed?  How is the context being disposed, and is there a way to prevent this? As you can see from the code below I'm using recursion, so creating a DbContext in the inner method is probably not a good idea.

**The Code:**

```
public static IEnumerable<Content> GetContent(int? parentId = null)
{
    using(DSSCMSContext context = new DSSCMSContext())
    {
        return context.Contents.Where(x => x.ParentId == parentId).ToList().Select(x => 
            {
                Content content = new Content(x);
                content.GetChildContent(context);
                return content;
            });          
    }
}

private void GetChildContent(DSSCMSContext context)
{
    Children = context.Contents.Where(x => x.ParentId == Id).ToList().Select(x =>
    {
        Content child = new Content(x);
        child.GetChildContent(context);
        return child;
    });
}
```

Comment: Off Topic, but this is a horrible design and that's helping to cause this kind of problem. The Content classes should not know about the Context.

Comment: The context itself is just being used to retrieve objects based off a property.  The output is then used to construct model objects.  If the content class doesn't know about the context how do you convert a EF object into a Model object - given that binding the frontend directly to EF objects is not a good idea.

Comment: "binding the frontend directly to EF objects is not ..." is a call for ViewModels. Binding (depending) either Models, ViewModels or DAOs on the DAL is not a good idea either.

Comment: So you'd always have a separate layer which converted between the DAL and Models (or equivalent)? If my memory isn't playing up, that's essentially a repository pattern.  Thanks for the comment btw - I'll go away and have a think about it.

Comment: Yes, that layer is the DAL (with Repository a possible pattern). Models,especially Domain Models, should be persistence-agnostic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You return `IEnumerable` from `GetContent`. That means your last `Select` in `GetContent` will not be executed immediately (`Select` is lazily evaluated), it will be executed only when something enumerates the result of `GetContent`. But when something enumerates result of `GetContent` - your context is already disposed. Inside that `Select` you call `content.GetChildContent(context)`. This method assumes context is alive but it is not.

One fix is enumerate result yourself before returning from the method:

```
return context.Contents.Where(x => x.ParentId == parentId).AsEnumerable().Select(x => 
{
     Content content = new Content(x);
     content.GetChildContent(context);
     return content;
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks - I said it was probably trivial :)  Will accept when minimum time has passed.  I even knew that - just hadn't considered it as I was refactoring that method

Comment: The OP probably needs that `.ToList()` at 2 levels. But the interleaving of Model and DAL makes it a little hard to be sure.

Comment: Yes - as written the first .ToList() is required to enable the use of methods within the linq statement which can't be converted directly to SQL.

Comment: @C.Knight it's a little bit better to use `AsEnumerable` for that (will remove unnecessary conversion to list).

Comment: Yeah - thanks, the .ToList() was just a quick placeholder to try and prototype the functionality.  Will clean it up now I've got it working (thanks to your answer)

Answer (score -2):

```
  public static IEnumerable<Content> GetContent(int? parentId = null)
    {
        using(DSSCMSContext context = new DSSCMSContext())
        {
            return context.Contents.Where(x => x.ParentId == parentId).ToList().Select(x => 
                {
                    Content content = new Content(x);
                    content.GetChildContent(context);
                    return content;
                });          
        }
    }

    private void GetChildContent(DSSCMSContext context)
    {
        Children = context.Contents.Where(x => x.ParentId == Id).ToList().Select(x =>
        {
            Content child = new Content(x);
            child.GetChildContent(context);
child.Dispose();
                return child;
            });
        }
```

Comment: umm.... not sure I see how that will work.  The context itself is being disposed - which means that the line of code you've added will never be called

Comment: Perhaps you could provide at least *some* explanation of what the problem was, what you changed, and how that change addresses the problem?  Randomly dumping code isn't really how Stack Overflow works.